# Getting many to many relation data in EF

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to Entity framework, struggling to get it right.
I have sql server three tables,

- 1st table contains Parent Object's detail
- 2nd table contains Child
  Object's detail
- 3rd table has 2 column Parent_Id and Child_Id, for
  mapping as a parent can have multiple children.

I am using database first approach and Entity Framework 5. Generated DbContext has only 2 class (mapping table does not have corresponding class).

Parent Class has `ICollection<Child>` and Child Class has `ICollection<Parent>`.

I want to get list of child object, based on parent id, if I use

```
context.Parent
       .Include(f => f.Child)   
       .FirstOrDefault(f => f.ParentId == RequiredParentId)
```

where RequiredParentId is my filter. This gives me parent object, however I want to retrive only list of childs in Parent. If I change this to

```
context.Parent
       .Include(f => f.Child)   
       .FirstOrDefault(f => f.ParentId == RequiredParentId)
       .Child
```

Then If parent is not in database, than ".Child" will throw exception. Also I dont want to load any data for parent, I am just interested in getting list of child based on parent Id.

I also tried writing it another way

```
   context.Child
         .Include(f => f.Parent)
         .Select(f => f.Parent.FirstOrDefault().ParentId == RequiredParentId);
```

Here again `.Select(f => f.Parent.FirstOrDefault().ParentId` will throw exception if there is no child for parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
context.Parent.Where(e => e.ParentId == RequiredParentId).SelectMany(e => e.Child)
```

If the Parent doesn't exist or if no children exist, the resulting collection will be empty.

NOTE: If there are multiple Parents with the same ID this will join the Children of each (with duplicates). I'm assuming that ParentId is the Key for Parent, and thus will not have duplicates

Comment: Thanks for answering!